# Sum of rows conditional on two conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-statements

I'd like to use array function to get conditional sum based on two columns. Given the example, for each ID I want to calculate the sum of value column if column B is -1

```
ID | B | value |
________________
A1   1     2
A2   1     3
A3   1     4
A3  -1     5
A3  -1     1
A2   1     5
A1   1     1
A2  -1     2
```

The outcome should be

```
ID | value_total |
__________________
A1  1      0
A2  1      2
A3  1      6
```

Comment: You want to sum `col C` for each unique value in `col A` when `col B` is `-1`? And you want a formula, not a macro?

Comment: You probably want a [sumifs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx)

Comment: @Excellll What is the point in having "Microsoft-excel" and "Microsoft-excel-2010" both as tag? You can have all Excel questions in your favorite list with `*excel*` as tag. Note the placeholders

Comment: @nixda See meta in a few places: http://meta.superuser.com/q/7105/76571 http://meta.superuser.com/q/1261/76571

Comment: @Excellll Thank you, I already know them. In fact I thought a lot about them. I realized that there is confusion about this topic, so I try to convince others to remove redundant tags too. In this specific question, I may have chosen the wrong one since its more of a general Excel question. Please note that I would never remove e.g "debian" and let "linux" in place. This is only about Excel and its versions

Comment: @nixda ha I didn't look to see that your previous edit was to remove the general tag. I just happened to see it on the front page and I thought I'd fix it. Anyhow, I think the general tag is useful because it lets users of other versions know that the solutions here should apply to them as well. For instance I wouldn't want a novice Excel 2007 user to think `SUMIFS` was new to Excel 2010 and unavailable to them based on the tagging of the question. I suggest posting on Meta if you think Excel tagging should work a certain way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `=sumifs()` in excel versions later that 2007. Here is [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx)

Syntax:

`SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], …)`

`=sumifs(C2:C9, A2:A9, "A#", B2:B9, "-1")`